# Validation via cin

Tags: c++, validation, cin

I'm new to C++ and experimenting...

I'm trying to validate an input via `cin`:

```
if(!cin){  
    cin.clear(); // without this: infinite
    cin.ignore();
    returnText = "Sorry, I can`t do that. :(";
             
}else if(input == sum){
    returnText = "Great, you did it! :)";
          
}else{
    returnText =  "Sorry, the correct result would have been " + to_string(sum) + ". :("; 
}
         
cout << returnText << "\n\n";
```

It does work (somehow), except it loops for each single not-valid char.

Is there a way to check only after hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>? And then for the whole `cin` instead of chars?

(Maybe silly, as it represents chars, but would be nice)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use

```cpp
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

instead of

```cpp
cin.ignore();
```

to ignore until newline character instead of ignoring only one character.

Comment: I agree this is an ideal answer for real world software. However, say someone is learning programming, or attempting to avoid using the std namespace when possible. This seems awfully complicated to do something that should be simple such as parsing user input. This is why I've always opted for using C routines for input/output. `cin`/`cout` seem to have intricacies that overly complicate I/O.

Comment: To be honest, I like the idea of using cin for validation. 
I had another solution with a regex before - better chaining different regex's - as I want to use it for a concatenated cin like cin >> validNum >> operator >> validNum....
This snippet is just my "playfile".
But I'm totally new to C/C++ and don't know of the other ways and possibilities, so I can't judge that...
For now I'm happy it behaves ;)